# Trying to input a file in java using a buffered-reader. Getting a FileNotFoundError

Tags: java, input, buffered

This is the error I experience when trying to parse a incoming file:

> Error in Parsing file.
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: input.txt (The system cannot find the file 
>       specified)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.FileReader.(Unknown Source)
>       at MovieDatabaseManager.parseInputFile(MovieDatabaseManager.java:47)
>       at MovieDatabaseManager.(MovieDatabaseManager.java:32)
>       at MovieDatabaseManager.main(MovieDatabaseManager.java:206)

Here is the code:

```
public MovieDatabaseManager(String file)
{
    this();
    parseInputFile(file); //populates database with list of movies
}

/**
 * Parses the input file so that you can add all of items found in the list 
in alphabetical order by title.
 */
private void parseInputFile(String file)
{
    //Create a file input stream
    Movie m;
    String instr;

    try 
    {
        //Create input reader
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while (in.ready())
        {
            instr = in.readLine();

            //Try to parse the movie using the appropriate movie 
            //constructor.  If it fails, an exception is caught
            try 
            {
                m = new Movie(instr);

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //Add code to insert m here into your list
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            } 
            catch (InvalidMovieException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid movie string " + instr + " in 
`enter code here`file " + file);
            }

        }
    } 
    catch (IOException io) 
    {
        System.err.println("Error in Parsing file.");
        io.printStackTrace();   
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your file path is probably incorrect

Comment: What @pruntlar said. Your program is almost certainly not looking in the correct spot for the file.

Comment: You need to learn what a *relative file name* and a *current directory* are.  They are not specific to Java, but rather are general computing concepts which are necessary to know before you can effectively work with files.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the full qualified path name of your resource to get it.

Ex: C:/dur/dir/file.txt

Else, relative path can be used for files in the same hierarchy of the jar file executed.

Comment: A relative path is relative to the current working directory. It has nothing to do with the 'same hierarchy of the jar file executed'.

Comment: When running from Jar its from the Jar path, when running from Eclipse its from working directory, If using getClass().getResource() its from the class-path